# Plotting different series with different lengths quantmod

Tags: r, quantmod

I want to plot cumsum line for each year of a series, but the thing is each year have different observations. I have tried using Chart_series but it doesn't work.

My goal is to plotting lines as years in terms of cumulative evolution.

In the example I put only two years.

```
library(PerformanceAnalytics)
library(quantmod)
library(tidyverse)
library(tidyquant)

library(xts)

a<-dailyReturn(TSLA,subset='2020') 
a2019<-dailyReturn(TSLA,subset='2019') 
b<-cumsum(a)*100
b2019<-cumsum(a2019)*100
plot(b2019)
lines(b)
```

Answer (score 1):

We could get a single dataset and then do a group by `cumsum` before plotting

```
library(dplyr)
library(tibble)
library(lubridate)
library(PerformanceAnalytics)
library(quantmod)
library(ggplot2)

getSymbols('TSLA')
dailyReturn(TSLA, subset = c('2019', '2020')) %>%
    as.data.frame %>% 
    rownames_to_column('Date')  %>%
    mutate(Date = as.Date(Date)) %>% 
    group_by(Year = year(Date)) %>% 
    mutate(CumDaily.returns = cumsum(daily.returns) * 100) %>% 
    ggplot(aes(x = Date, y = CumDaily.returns, color = Year)) + 
         geom_line() +
         theme_bw()
```

-output

[image]

Comment: Many thanks, the thing is I want to plot all different years in a fixed plot, x-axis always would be from 01/01 to 31/12 as much lines as years so I can compare the evolution in a year with other in the same plot. So in the graph I want to make, always maximum values would be 365/366 observations of a year.

Comment: I am trying to make something like this but I cant
getSymbols('TSLA')

as.data.frame %>% 
    rownames_to_column('Date')  %>%
    mutate(Date = as.Date(Date)) %>% 

a<-cumsum(dailyReturn(TSLA, subset = c('2019')) ) %>%

b<-cumsum(dailyReturn(TSLA, subset = c('2020')) ) %>%
    
   c<-cumsum(dailyReturn(TSLA, subset = c('2018')) ) %>%

ggplot(a, aes(x=Date)) + 
  geom_line(aes(y = b), color = "darkred") + 
  geom_line(aes(y = c), color="steelblue", linetype="twodash")